# DirectX 11 optimization with "waitable object"

Tags: directx-11

As explained at [Optimizing DirectX apps for low latency input...](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/12/18/optimizing-directx-apps-for-low-latency-input-and-longer-battery-life/), the use of **DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_FRAME_LATENCY_WAITABLE_OBJECT** can make the application more responsive. I have a couple of questions on this:

1. Why can't I achieve the same effect just by waiting for previous call to "Present1" to end, before performing the next game loop?
2. According to [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn448914.aspx) I can get the waitable object by creating the swap chain with **CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow**. Is there a way of getting a **CoreWindow** from regular Win32 application (not Windows Store app)?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to `Present` (or `Present1`) is non-blocking and returns pretty quickly. It just indicates to the API that you are done with the frame and are ready to show the frame buffer. In order to keep the CPU from getting too far ahead of the GPU, Windows by default will block on the `Present` once 3 frames are queued up. This normally will smooth out in apps at some steady-rate, but this additional latency can be a real problem for touch-based UI applications.

CoreWindow APIs are only usable for WinRT-based platforms like UWP for Windows 10, Windows Store, Windows phone 8, and Xbox one. They are not usable for Windows desktop apps.

What you can do in a Windows desktop app is use the `DXGI_PRESENT_DO_NOT_WAIT` flag and if the `Present` returns a failure code of `DXGI_PRESENT_DO_NOT_WAIT` your applications knows that it's got a number of frames queued up. You could do other work to wait a bit, throttle your content, or do other clever things with this but most games just run 'flat out' and let the game block if it's rendering too fast.

Comment: So actually, even when I see that **Present1** is returning every 16ish msec, actually it returns when a buffer is queued, and it's not an indication that the buffer was presented to the user?
Is the number of "3 frames" you mentioned - some magical number, or it can be changed?

Comment: I have also looked at `DXGI_PRESENT_DO_NOT_WAIT`, seems like this still does not tell me when the frame was presented, only that the frame was queued without blocking, right? 
So is there any way to know when the frame is actually shown to the user? Ideally I want to know the absolute time of the presentation, to do correct prediction of the objects for that time.
I also tried using `IDXGIOutput->WaitForVBlank()`, it seems to give reasonable results, but the accuracy is low.

Comment: After doing some more tests, seems like I get the best results by performing `Present(0)`, followed by `WaitForVBlank()`. Does this make sense?

Comment: That likely minimizes latency, but I suspect you are wasting a lot of GPU performance doing that...

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate on the GPU performance wasting? I assumed that while I'm in `WaitForVBlank` the CPU/GPU are not being occupied, so effectively I'm calling `Present` once per frame. Isn't this the case?

Comment: The default behavior of ``Present`` is to let your CPU process up to three frames ahead, and the GPU can work in parallel on those frames. If the CPU gets three frames ahead, ``Present`` blocks until the GPU finishes up a frame and then the CPU is free to work again. This allows both the CPU and GPU to work in tandem, not in lock-step. By using ``WaitForVBlank`` you are most likely idling *both* the GPU and CPU where the system specifications exceed your minimum.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn You can use the waitable-object flag with [`CreateSwapChainForHwnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404557(v=vs.85).aspx) as well.  The feature isn't limited to CoreWindow-based apps.

Comment: My mistake. It appears you can with the limitation that you can't use ``DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD`` and must use ``DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL``, and it will only work on Windows 8.1 or Windows 10--the feature is not present on Windows 8.0 or Windows 7 even with the DirectX 11.1 update.

Comment: This starts making more sense, thanks a lot! I was able to create a waitable chain with `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL` as you instructed, it also required to specify at lease 2 back buffers in `BufferCount` field. Assuming that I will always call `Present(0)` , what is the meaning of having two back buffers?

Comment: Flip has to have at least 2 buffers: one is the 'front' (not truly the display front buffer, but the one that the Desktop Windows Compositor uses) and one is the 'back' that your app can render to.